# how to check if content txt file has changed

Tags: javascript

Situation:
I am reading the content of a .txt file with php and with AJAX i load the content into a div. The javascript checks every 5 seconds the .txt file and put the content into the div.
If the content of the .txt file changes, (which i do with a form submit), the content of the div changes automatically after 5 seconds.
For this; i use a checkbox with 3 options:
Status: Available
Status: Busy
Status: Paused

One of the 3 lines above is in the .txt file.
Situation now: every 5 seconds check of the .txt file and every 5 seconds refresh of the div. Is it possible that if the content of the .txt file has not changed, to keep the refresh away?

How can i achieve this?

Below the javascript:

```
 function Ajax()
    {
        var
            $http,
            $self = arguments.callee;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            } catch(e) {
                $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
        }

        if ($http) {
            $http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                    document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                    setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 5000);
                }
            };
            $http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
            $http.send(null);
        }

    }
```

Loadtxt.php

```
<?php
        //
        $file = "status.txt";
        $f = fopen($file, "r");
        while ( $line = fgets($f, 5000) ) {
        echo $line;
        }
?>
```

The div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 5000);
</script>
<div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>
```

Comment: Someone needs to check if the text file has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the HASH of the file on the server-side have your AJAX check with the for the hash (say a SHA1 or an MD5) - and only update the DIV if the hash has changed since it last looked ?

Maybe this PHP function on the server could help here ?

```
string hash_file ( string $algo , string $filename [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

Which I found on this link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php

So something like this (I am not in a position to test this; so edits are very welcome here):

filehash.php:

```
<?php
    $file = "status.txt";
    echo hash_file( "SHA1", $file, $raw_output=false )
?>
```

Set up a Javascript variable like 'fileHash':

```
var fileHash;
```

populate with an AJAX call to the new PHP script:

```
[...]
     $http.open('GET', 'filehash.php' , true);
     newFileHash=$http.responseText;
     if (fileHash!=newFileHash) { // file changed - so fetch contents
         [...]
         // check me here: can we just make use of $http twice here ?
         $http.open('GET', 'loadtxt.php' + '?' + new Date().getTime(), true);
         // update div.
         document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML =$http.responseText;
         fileHash=newFileHash;
     } 
     setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 5000);
[...]
```

Alternative suggestion:

Your webserver might be able to automatically return a HTTP code to state that the file hasn't changed since it was last requested (by comparing with your browser headers) - with an HTTP 304 for instance:

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> 304 Not Modified
>       Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or
>   If-None-Match. This means that there is no need to retransmit the
>   resource, since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy.

It looks like you have added a timestamp parameter to your GET request - which I presume is prevent your browser caching the old copy of the text file: if you do opt for the method above, you should remove this from your GET request - as this will appear to the webserver that you are asking for a new document each time.